# What if Z value I want isn't in the table?

Tags: probability, statistics

We have a normal distribution of salary. We are told that 25% of the salary workers earn below 180 000 dollars and 25% percent earn above 320 000 dollars.

I want to find the Z value associated with P( X < 180 000).

I look up the solution and this is what I see:

P( X < 180 000) = 0.25

P( X < $\dfrac{180000- \mu }{\sigma}$) = 0.25

We should then find what is the corresponding value to 0.25 in the Z table. However this value isn't there. My Z table starts with 0.5000. I actually want to find $\dfrac{180000- \mu }{\sigma}$.

What do I do?

**Update: In the solution they say that Z = $\dfrac{180000- \mu }{\sigma}$ = -0.675 but I have no idea how it was found because even if it was 0.675 I don't know how it relates to the Z table.**

Comment: Consider looking at $0.75$ instead.  How should the value for $0.75$ be related to the value you should have expected for $0.25$?  Should these be equal?  Should these add up to $1$?  Should they be related in some other way?

Comment: I have updated the question to add clarification.

Comment: The first line tells you that $P(X \lt 180\ 000)=0.25$, so you can stop there.

Comment: Yes but no I want to find the value of Z so I can use it to find other probabilities. I've edited the question to reflect this more.

Answer (score 1):

You are expected to use the fact that the normal distribution is symmetric about the mean.  Because the percentages outside $180000$ and $320000$ are the same, the mean is halfway in between, so $\mu=\frac 12(180000+320000)=200000$  Now we need to evaluate the standard deviation.  The [Z-score table in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table#Cumulative_from_mean_(0_to_Z)) lists the chance a random variable is between the mean and some value above the mean.  The chance the variable is less than the mean is $\frac 12$.  We know that $0.75$ of the area is below $320000$ so we need $0.25$ of the area to be between $200000$ and $320000$.  We look in the body of the table for $0.25$ and find it is between the values for $+0.67\sigma$ and $+0.68 \sigma$, so the value $320000$ is $0.675$ sigma above the mean.  We then have $\sigma\approx \frac {320000-200000}{0.675}\approx 178000.$